# In PHP getting "Class 'PDO' not found" error while trying to connect to Oracle DB

Tags: php, oracle, pdo

I am trying to connect to my oracle database using PDO but I am getting **Class PDO not found error.** I have checked that PDO is enabled and it appears so. Still I am not able to trace why I am getting this error. Here is my configure command,

```
cscript /nologo configure.js "--enable-snapshot-build" "--enable-debug-pack" 
"--with-snapshot-template=d:\php-sdk\snap_5_2\vc6\x86\template" 
"--with-php-build=d:\php-sdk\snap_5_2\vc6\x86\php_build" 
"--with-pdo-oci=D:\php-sdk\oracle\instantclient10\sdk,shared" 
"--with-oci8=D:\php-sdk\oracle\instantclient10\sdk,shared"
```

PHP ver : 5.2.8
Oracle: 10.2

This is the code I am using to connect to the db.

```
try{
    $conn = new PDO("oci:dbname=".$oc_db,$oc_user,$oc_pass);
}catch(PDOException $e){
    echo ($e->getMessage());
}
```

Can there be any other reason that I am getting this error? Any help appreciated.

Comment: PDO needs the general PDO module and driver specific modules (in your case php_oracle) enabled. What does a call to phpinfo() output in the PDO section 'PDO drivers'? Which specific drivers are enabled?

Comment: since you mention this I checked out again in phpinfo() but there is no section for "PDO drivers".

Comment: Ah yes, of course, I guess that makes sense since you mentioned class PDO isn't found. Silly me. I'm afraid I'm not too experienced with configuring PHP the way you are configuring it. But my guess is you should have another config option along the lines of '--with-pdo' that installs the general PDO module. This is assuming '--with-pdo-oci' doesn't automatically install the general PDO module. Not sure about that though.

Comment: @fireeyedboy: you should post this in an answer, not a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This generally means the PDO extension in question isn't compiled and set up so PHP can use it. What operating system are you compiling PHP on?

I'm not sure if PDO core module is compiled if you only specify to compile the oracle extension of it (PDO-OCI).

You should check out the PHP manual regarding how to install and enable the PDO module.

You should look at these sites:
http://is.php.net/manual/en/pdo.installation.php
http://is.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-oci.php

Comment: I (actually, my webmaster) am compiling it on Windows Box. I think he had not installed the PDO_OCI but it was sorted out. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check my question I troubleshoot this and other errors but then Im stuck,
[No records found ...Agiletoolkit and Oracle. Grid/CRUD elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25798501/no-records-found-agiletoolkit-and-oracle-grid-crud-elements)

My Oracle connection string in agiletoolkit config-default.php file looks like this:

```
$config['dsn']= array( 'oci:dbname=localhost/MYDATABASE', 'MYUSER', 'MYPASSWORD' );
```

To fix the driver not found error, I enabled extension=php_pdo_oci8.dll in the php.ini file from my apache installation.

Then there was an error about a missing "oci.php", to solve that I had to create my own file like this:

```
class DB_dsql_oci extends DB_dsql {
    function limit($cnt,$shift=0){
        $cnt+=$shift;

    $this->where('NUM_ROWS>=',$shift);
        $this->where('NUM_ROWS<',$cnt);
        return $this;
    }
    function render_limit(){
        return '';
    }
}
```

and placed it at: ...atk4\lib\DB\dsql

To fix the special chars error from oracle , I set line 59 on /atk4/lib/DB/dsql.php to empty string like this: `public $bt='';`

I manage to run the database test, and it says "Successfully connected to database."