# CMS for a single page management

Tags: php, content-management-system

I need a little help. I have a website with a page for careers where our company post new vacancies. Website do not run on any CMS, but I want only this job posting page to run on CMS, so that it would be easy to post jobs without editing PHP files.

can you help with some open source CMS I can use for this. That CMS will only run that particular page not the whole website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with Bobby - installing a CMS for such purpose is a huge overkill though I agree with you that it'll be much easier to manage for non-technical users.

I would advise against wordpress (it would be very slow and require a lot of work only to optimize the speed). 
My choice would be Joomla, (Drupal should work fine as well). 
I didn't use Joomla 3.0 so I'm not sure about it - but older versions will run pretty fast and will be easy to use (edit new job posts).

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any programming experience? Depending upon the exact requirements, this could well be easier and more efficient written from scratch in your scripting language of choice, rather than using a heavy, general purpose piece of off-the-shelf software, which might not fit your needs exactly.

Comment: i have already wriiten a cms from scratch but its giving some PDO error, which i think of because my hosting company runs php 5.2 rather that 5.3. though you can check it here www.innovatrix.co.in/cms

Comment: I don't think that's due to the PHP version, as such, but how it's been installed - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436264/in-php-getting-class-pdo-not-found-error-while-trying-to-connect-to-oracle-d