# No records found ...Agiletoolkit and Oracle. Grid/CRUD elements

Tags: php, user-interface, frameworks, atk4

I am trying to test around Agile Toolkit with oracle, after seting up a model and trying to show a grid it says "No records found"...

Let me tell you what I did, since i've been guessing most of all configuration as I found no guides for oracle.

- My Oracle connection string in agiletoolkit config-default.php file looks like this:

  $config['dsn']= array( 'oci:dbname=localhost/MYDATABASE', 'MYUSER', 'MYPASSWORD' );
- To fix the driver not found error, I enabled `extension=php_pdo_oci8.dll`  in the php.ini  file from my apache installation.
- Then there was an error about a missing "oci.php", to solve that I had to create my own file like this:

  ```
  class DB_dsql_oci extends DB_dsql {
      function limit($cnt,$shift=0){
          $cnt+=$shift;

      $this->where('NUM_ROWS>=',$shift);
          $this->where('NUM_ROWS<',$cnt);
          return $this;
      }
      function render_limit(){
          return '';
      }
  }
  ```

and placed it at: `...atk4\lib\DB\dsql`

- To fix the special chars error from oracle ,  I set line 59 on  /atk4/lib/DB/dsql.php to empty string like this:    `public $bt='';`

I manage to run the database test, and it says "Successfully connected to database."

Then I created a model "lib\Model\Mytable.php" like this:

```
    <?php
    class Model_Mytable extends Model_Table {
        public $table = "MYTABLE";
        function init(){
            parent::init();

            $this->addField('ID');
            $this->addField('NAME');
            $this->addField('INIDATE');
            $this->addField('ENDDATE');     


        }
?>
```

After that, I made a new page and tried to use the model like this:

```
<?php
    class page_test extends Page {
    function init(){
        parent::init();


    $form = $this->add('Grid');
    $form->setModel('Mytable');



    }
}
?>
```

After refreshing the browser, it will show the grid saying " No Records found"

I wonder whats happening, that table has records no doubt, all data is committed, and im sure oracle is parsing queries because if I miss a column name an oracle error will raise.

Any clue?

Comment: Which ATK version do you use (from homepage or 4.2/master from GitHub or upcomming 4.3 from GitHub)? Model_Table is deprecated, better use SQL_Model. I see some naming issues - better name your tables and table fields in lowercase. Also you shouldn't add ID field - it's added automatically by Model class. Your render_limit method looks suspicious, but it shouldn't break anything (except not limiting resultset). Assigning CRUD object to variable $form is not good style. That of course doesn't break anything, but you can mix something later in your code :)

Comment: And don't change ATK classes directly as you did in /atk4/lib/DB/dsql.php. Extend them and overwrite. In your case put $bt='' in your DB_dsql_oci class and it'll overwrite dsql class $bt attribute.

Comment: Those changes deserve to be inside the framework. I don't have an oracle database to test with, so thanks for reporting all of the above. @Adrian, could you you try and get some data through DSQL as explained here: http://book.agiletoolkit.org/model/dsql.html

Comment: Im using  4.2.4  which is available at the site for download, Thanks for the coments DarkSide will try to keep good practices as you mention.
Thanks for the link romanish, I will try that just now and let you know guys ;)

Comment: Ok Using DSQL allows me to query some data, I'm looking how to add that to a view now, is that possible?

Comment: Im using it like this:

$q = $this->api->db->dsql();
$q->table('MYTABLE')->field('DNAME')->field('INIDATE');

 



 foreach($q as $row) {
  echo $row['DNAME'];
  
 }

And it prints data, i'm unsure how to add this to a view.

Comment: And yes, in Model class you can add `$this->debug()` in `init` method. Then you should see SQL request which model generates. See if it's correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you can simply set DSQL as your View (Grid for example) data source:

```
class page_test extends Page_Basic
{
    function init()
    {
        parent::init();

        // DSQL
        $q = $this->api->db->dsql();
        $q->table('MYTABLE')
                ->field('DNAME')
                ->field('INIDATE');

        // Create grid and set DSQL as its data source
        $g = $this->add('Grid');
        $g->addColumn('DNAME');
        $g->addColumn('INIDATE');
        $g->setSource($q);

        // better add paginator too or your grid can become huge :)
        $g->addPaginator();
    }
}
```